# select nearest time for sequential dates

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

lets say I have list of dates in datetime format:

```
6/30/2015 10:44:44 PM
6/30/2015 11:00:24 PM 
7/1/2015 12:22:46 AM    
7/1/2015 12:26:38 AM 
7/1/2015 2:55:04 AM 
7/1/2015 3:23:00 AM 
7/1/2015 3:32:09 AM 
7/1/2015 3:52:27 AM 
7/1/2015 3:57:25 AM 
7/1/2015 4:03:34 AM 
7/1/2015 4:23:52 AM 
7/1/2015 4:32:00 AM 
7/1/2015 4:50:03 AM    
7/1/2015 4:54:46 AM 
7/1/2015 5:10:20 AM 
7/1/2015 5:13:37 AM 
7/1/2015 5:18:51 AM 
.... 
7/31/2015 11:18:51 PM
```

and I would like to grab a nearest time to 5AM for every date in the list.
How should I go about it?

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM x
WHERE x.date < @CurrentDate
ORDER BY x.date DESC
```

should grab the nearest date to the current date, but for every different date?

Comment: Do you mean the nearest the nearest before OR after 5AM?

Comment: Hint, use TIMEDIFF() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `TIMEDIFF` and `TIME_TO_SEC` method to get the "nearest" date to some other date:

```
SELECT 
  d 
FROM 
  test 
ORDER BY 
  ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, "2015-10-23 19:00:00")))
LIMIT 
  0,1 ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b67f/2

To get the closed date *per day* and available entry, you need to extend this query, so it doesn't compare with a fixed date, but "5 AM every Day":

To achieve this:

- Calculate the minimum offset of every entry towards it's *5 AM date*
- Group by `DATE(d)`
- **Now the crucial point**: rather than selecting the `date` ( or `min(date)`) which might be wrong due to grouping* (note at end of post), we use the date we are *targeting* plus (or minus) the offset (which is *correct* due to grouping along with the `min()` aggregation)

In the Example `DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)` is used to determine `7 pm` for the current row. For `5 am` it would be `DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)` :

(I left the columns for debugging in the query, they can be removed ofc. You only need the `actualDate`-Column)

```
SELECT 
  DATE(d) AS day,
  MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR))))) AS offset,
  MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) AS controlOffset1,
  MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR),d))) AS controlOffset2,
  CASE
      WHEN MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR))))) = MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) && MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) > 0 THEN
       DATE_Add(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR), INTERVAL 
         MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))))               
       SECOND)  
      WHEN MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR))))) = MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR),d))) THEN
       DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR), INTERVAL 
         MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))))               
       SECOND)  
      WHEN MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) = MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR),d))) THEN
       DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR), INTERVAL 
         MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))))               
       SECOND)  
        WHEN MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) <> MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR),d))) THEN
        DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR), INTERVAL 
         MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))))               
       SECOND)  
      END AS actualDate,
      case 

      WHEN MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR))))) = MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) && MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) > 0 THEN
        "TEST#1"
        WHEN MIN(ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR))))) = MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR),d))) THEN
        "TEST#2"
        WHEN MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) = MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR),d))) THEN
        "TEST#3"
        WHEN MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(d, DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR)))) <> MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(DATE(d), INTERVAL 19 HOUR),d))) THEN
        "TEST#4"
      END AS testCase
FROM 
  test 
GROUP BY DATE(d)
```

Data:

```
     CREATE table test (d datetime);

 # TEST 1: Solution later
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-23 19:10:00"); #this
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-23 19:20:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-23 19:30:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-23 19:40:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-23 19:50:00");

 # TEST 2: Solution earlier
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-24 18:10:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-24 18:20:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-24 18:30:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-24 18:40:00"); 
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-24 18:50:00");#this

 # TEST 3: Solution later, but earlier available
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-25 18:30:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-25 18:40:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-25 18:50:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-25 19:05:00"); #this
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-25 19:10:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-25 19:20:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-25 19:30:00");

 # Test 4: Solution earlier, but later available
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 18:30:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 18:40:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 18:50:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 18:55:00"); #this
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 19:10:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 19:20:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 19:30:00");
 INSERT INTO test (d) values ("2015-10-26 19:40:00");
```

Result:

```
day                         offset  controlOffset1  controlOffset2  actualDate                  testCase
October, 23 2015 00:00:00   600     600             -3000            October, 23 2015 19:10:00  TEST#1
October, 24 2015 00:00:00   600     -3000           600              October, 24 2015 18:50:00  TEST#2
October, 25 2015 00:00:00   300     -1800           -1800            October, 25 2015 19:05:00  TEST#3
October, 26 2015 00:00:00   300     -1800           -2400            October, 26 2015 18:55:00  TEST#4
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/951b5/22

Explanation:

- When we have determined the `Min(Abs())` offset, we need to figure out, if we need to `add` this offset to the `7pm` value, or `subtract` it.
- We are using 2 control offsets for the determination:

  - controlOffset1: `MIN(actualDate - 7pm)`
  - controlOffset2: `MIN(7pm - actualDate)`
- Case 1: **offset matches controlOffset1**: We have an actualDate LATER than the target -> Use `DATE_ADD`
- Case 2: **offset matches controlOffset2**: We have an actualDate EARLIER than the target -> Use `DATE_SUB`
- Case 3: **controlOffset1 matches controlOffset2**: We have an actualDate LATER than the target, but other dates before: Use `DATE_ADD`
- Case 4: **Everything not even matching case 3**: Musst be case 4, use `DATE_SUB` :-)

The only thing *undertermined* might now be, if two dates are +/- with the same offset, i.e. +/- 5 Minutes. Therefore the result is undetermined anyway, so you should be able to get non-null values by extending some conditions with `>=` or `<=`. (Edit: will be matched with case 3, picking the later date: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21f2ce/2)

ps.: It would be interesting how the final solution behaves performance wise, compared to the "single-fetch" in an application-side iterative approach.

*compare the offsets: Why is `Min(d - 7pm)` a different offset than `Min(7pm -d)` - and not only the sign? Because `d` is undetermined due to missing aggregation. So with the two *control offsets* we can determine values depending on `7pm` that *are* aggregated properly and therefore reliable.)

Answer (score 0):

Considering both before and after 5 am on equal footing:

```
select d, min(if(diff < 0, subtime(subtime(diff,diff),diff), diff)) diff from(
    select date(d) d, timediff(time(d), maketime(5,0,0)) diff from dt
) q
group by d;
```